# Installing Ubuntu and Windows Vista on the same drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-vista, installation

Can Ubuntu and Windows Vista both be installed on the same drive?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to install both on the same drive, you have options:

- Install Vista. Install Ubuntu using the Windows setup tool provided on the Ubuntu CD; OR
- Partition the drive. Have Vista on one partition, and Ubuntu on the other (my preference)

Comment: If it wasn't clear, I suggest you install Windows first, because dual-booting is easier that way.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://apcmag.com/how_to_dualboot_vista_with_linux_vista_installed_first.htm) out.

Maybe you should try google first before asking questions here.

Comment: Questions that have technical merit are encouraged on this site, even if the answer can be quickly googled. Please see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions and this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers. They constitute the official extended "faq" questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Vista installed, if I remember correctly Boot into Vista and Run the Ubuntu disk, it will then ask you to install Ubuntu on top of Vista. But my personal choice would be to have two partitions. Install Vista on the one partition and Ubuntu on the second using filesystem ext4. I would suggest you install Windows Vista first and then Ubuntu, then the Grub loader will help you to choose between operating systems at startup.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Ubuntu Community Documentation Guide on [Dual Booting Ubuntu and Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot). It also has a [link to a step-by-step screenshot tutorial](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu) to set up an Ubuntu + Vista dual-boot.